# The concept of writing automatic tests for setting up an account

Tags: selenium, testing, automated-tests, cucumber

I am writing tests using selenium and cucumber, I wonder about using TestNG with cucumber? When Cucumber, when TestNG? Or Both?

I have example scenario like this:

```
  Scenario: Successful Create Account with Valid Credentials
    Given I am on Home Page
     When I Navigate to Create Account Page
      And I fill in "User Name" with <username>
      And I fill in "Password" with <password>
      And I fill in "Password" with <password>
      And I fill in "email" with <email>
     Then I see title "Congratulation you create account"
    Examples: 
      | username | password     | email          | 
      | Tom123   | password12   | Tom@gmailcom   | 
      | Kenny123 | fasfadfaadfa | Kenny@gmailcom |
```

This is simple confirm test, but if I would like to test my account creation using NastyString, and a lot of combinations?

```
  Scenario: Unsuccessful reate Account with invalid Credentials
    Given I am on Home Page
     When I Navigate to Create Account Page
      And I fill in "UserName" with incorrect credentials 
     Then I see error message
      And I fill in "password" with incorrect credentials
     Then I see error message
      And I fill in "email" with incorrect credentials
```

Scenario like this and tests using testNG with Data Provider with BDD style?

Comment: Whatever **NastyString** and however combination you use the implementation under the hood remains the same. Hence won't make any difference. To choose between `When Cucumber` and  `when TestNG` will depend on the _Subject Matter Expertise_ and the availability of required hardware/software/manpower along with intended timeline.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you have to use either TestNG with Cucumber ( both together ) or JUnit with Cucumber I prefer JUnit. The reason is with TestNG the creation of the Test Runner class is going to be a bit complicated. Since your tests are getting executed as cucumber tests you can use JUnit or TestNG Runner to run with the cucumber class

The runner class Will look like this

```
    package cucumber;

import cucumber.api.junit.Cucumber;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)

@CucumberOptions(
glue={"stepDefinition"},
features = ("Feature"),
plugin = {"html:CucumberReports/cucumber-html-report"}
)
public class testRunner { }
```

So you can run this with JUnit ( With TestNG also the same thing will happen )
So for your Question you have to use Cucumber with TestNG  / Cucumber with Junit and Have to Run the Runner Class with JUnit/TestNG while setting @Runwith annotation to cucumber.class , as in the above example

If you want to Use TestNG insted of JUnit here is a tutorial you can use : 
https://medium.com/agile-vision/cucumber-bdd-part-2-creating-a-sample-java-project-with-cucumber-testng-and-maven-127a1053c180

Answer (score 0):

Using Cucumber to do exhaustive testing like this is a tremendous waste of your time and of runtime.

In general a well written Cucumber scenario is at least one order of magnitude slower than a well written unit test, so if you want to do exhaustive tests, testing lower down your stack is very beneficial.

Additionally Cucumber scenarios are very verbose when you try and specify everything in the scenario. What most people do is write scenario outlines with large complex tables. This achieves the double negative of making creating lots of slow running tests, and makes you step definitions much more complicated. In Cucumber you can't loop and when testing exhaustively you have to specify every single condition. This greatly increases the cost of change.

With unit tests you are in a programming language so you can loop, map and do all sorts of things to get more tests for less effort.

Use Cucumber for what its good at - describing behaviour and driving development, its not a testing tool!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should check [QAF-Gherkin](https://qmetry.github.io/qaf/latest/gherkin_client.html) QAF is built upon TestNG for black-box testing. You can get all the features of TestNG including data-driven capability, method (scenario) level parallel execution and many more. It has it's own BDD implementation as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try [ginkgo4j](http://paulcwarren.github.io/ginkgo4j/)?  It uses Java 8 lambda's to promote building highly contextual tests like you are trying to do.  The above example would look a bit like this, for example:-

```
Describe("Successful Create Account with Valid Credentials", ()->{
  Context("Given I am on Home Page", () -> {
    BeforeEach({} -> {
      // java code to get home page
    });
    Context("When I Navigate to Create Account Page", () -> {
      BeforeEach({} -> {
        // java code to navigate to create account page
      });
      Context("And I fill in "User Name" with <username>", () -> {
        BeforeEach({} -> {
          // java code to enter username
        });
        Context("And I fill in "Password" with <password>", () -> {
          BeforeEach({} -> {
            // java code to enter password
          });
          Context("And I fill in "email" with <email>", () -> {
            BeforeEach({} -> {
              // java code to enter email
            });
            It("Then I see title "Congratulation you create account", () -> {
              // java code to click create button and assert success message
            });
          });
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The obvious advantage of this is that you never have to leave Java.